# ReactJs 0.14 - Find dom Node of dynamic element

Tags: reactjs

Every ***blessed*** example has a static ref, nothing when the element is dynamic -- ughh!

In my render section I have this:

```
  <ul>
     { this.state.navItems.map(this.showNavMenu.bind(this)) }
  </ul>
```

My showNavMenu returns a menu item and any children it may have.

```
showNavMenu(item) {
  const results = [];
  let subMenu = [];
  if(item.children !== undefined) {
    subMenu = fetchSubMenu(item.children); // it returns back an array
  }

  results.push (
     <li ref={ item.docId }>{ item.title }
       { subMenu }
     </li>
   )
 }
```

**Problem:**

The subMenu needs a left & top style position per item respective of where it's parent is on the page.

In javaScript I could do a query selector ...

```
const parent = document.querySelector('[ref=' + item.docId + ']');
```

but React will not let me use querySelector.

**Question:**

How can I make the call to fetch the children and pass along their parent's x & y:

```
showNavMenu(item) {
  const results = [];
  let subMenu = [];
  if(item.children !== undefined) {
    let children = item.children
    let parent = this.refs[item.docId]   <-- doesn't work, returns undefined
    xPos = ???? parent.???
    yPos = ???? parent.???
    subMenu  = fetchSubMenu(children, xPos, yPos);
  }

  results.push (
     <li ref={ item.docId }>{ item.title }
       { subMenu }
     </li>
   )
 }
```

Comment: You can't access refs inside `render`. You'll want to wait for `componentDidUpdate` or some other hook and access it then. http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html#cautions

Comment: I see that, but still doesn't solve my issue

Answer (score 0):

In showNavMenu create a state object with xPos and yPos.

```js
 componentDidMount = () => {
   var xpos = ReactDom.findDOMNode(this).pageX;
      var ypos = ReactDom.findDOMNode(this).pageY;
      this.setState({xPos: xpos, yPos: ypos});
 }
```

```js
if(item.children !== undefined && this.state.xPos > 0) {
  subMenu  = fetchSubMenu(children, this.state.xPos, this.state.yPos);
}
```

Comment: Looked good, I was excited when I read it, all the values are 0 though, :(

Comment: var rect = ReactDom.findDOMNode(this).getBoundingClientRect(); this.setState({xPos: rect.top, yPos: rect.left}); https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect